Aging of melting fuse
I have an issue. I performed lifetime tests on melting fuses which are built-up as dual-element fuses. That means that they have two conductive busbars inside.
I measured the shunt voltage and temperature over the fuse and at the end of the test I have a small decrease in shunt voltage with a immediately increasing voltage (see picture).
I think one of the first fuse elements melts earlier than the other. But with this explanation, the current density should increase very fast and the voltage normally has to increase in the same way. How can you explain the short decrease of the voltage. Is there anything regarding the current, which flows now in whole over just one element?


